# Splitting out build and deployment pipelines and can't figure out where the k8s manifest uploads need to go

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

So I took the system generated `azure-pipelines.yml` and now I'm splitting it out into `build.yaml` and `deployment.yaml` that each have their own pipelines in Azure DevOps.

I've added branch and build validation to the `production` branch so that PRs are required to merge to it. When a PR is created, it automatically runs the `Build`, and therefore `build.yaml` pipeline.

If it passes, it can be approved and merged into `production`. The merge then triggers the `Deployment`, and therefore `deployment.yaml` pipeline.

`Build` is working. `Deployment` is not and the reason is it can't find the k8s manifests... basically this section in the system generated `azure-pipelines.yml`:

```
- upload: k8s
  artifact: k8s
```

Here is the full context of what was automatically produced:

```
trigger:
- production

resources:
- repo: self

variables:

  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: '<GUID>'
  imageRepository: 'app'
  containerRegistry: 'appacr.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  imagePullSecret: 'appacr1c5a-auth'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an api image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)-api
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)/api/Dockerfile
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)

    - upload: k8s
      artifact: k8s

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  jobs:
    - deployment: Deploy
      displayName: Deploy
      pool:
        vmImage: $(vmImageName)
      environment: 'App Production AKS'
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - task: KubernetesManifest@0
              displayName: Create imagePullSecret
              inputs:
                action: createSecret
                secretName: $(imagePullSecret)
                kubernetesServiceConnection: 'App Production AKS'
                dockerRegistryEndpoint: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
            - task: KubernetesManifest@0
              displayName: Deploy to api Kubernetes cluster
              inputs:
                action: deploy
                kubernetesServiceConnection: 'App Production AKS'
                manifests: |
                  $(Pipeline.Workspace)/k8s/aks/api.yaml
                imagePullSecrets: |
                  $(imagePullSecret)
                containers: |
                  $(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository)-api:$(tag)
```

And this is how I have it split:

```
# build.yaml (works)
trigger: none

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
- template: templates/variables.yaml

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an api image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)-api
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)/api/Dockerfile
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
    - upload: k8s
      artifact: k8s
```

And...

```
# deployment.yaml (does not work)
trigger: 
  branches: 
    include:
    - production

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
- template: templates/variables.yaml

stages:
# - template: templates/changed.yaml
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  # dependsOn: Build
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: 'App Production AKS'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
            displayName: Publish k8s manifests
            inputs:
              targetPath: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/k8s
              artifactName: k8s
              artifactType: pipeline
          - task: KubernetesManifest@0
            displayName: Create imagePullSecret
            inputs:
              action: createSecret
              secretName: $(imagePullSecret)
              kubernetesServiceConnection: 'App Production AKS'
              dockerRegistryEndpoint: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)        
          - task: KubernetesManifest@0
            displayName: Deploy to api Kubernetes cluster
            inputs:
              action: deploy
              kubernetesServiceConnection: 'App Production AKS'
              manifests: |
                $(Pipeline.Workspace)/k8s/aks/api.yaml
              imagePullSecrets: |
                $(imagePullSecret)
              containers: |
                $(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository)-api:$(tag)
```

I've tried about a dozen different things for the publishing of the k8s manifests and the error message is usually something like:

```
##[error]Path does not exist: /home/vsts/work/1/s/k8s

# or 

##[error]No manifest file(s) matching /home/vsts/work/1/k8s/aks/api.yaml was found.
```

Suggestions for how to resolve this?

There is obviously some concept I am failing to grasp completely.

Comment: Publish the manifests as a build artifact, or clone the repository containing the manifests during your deployment pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, whether or not this is considered good/practice is another matter, but I did get it working with the following:

```
# deployment.yaml (does not work)
trigger: 
  branches: 
    include:
    - production

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
- template: templates/variables.yaml

stages:
- stage: Publish
  displayName: Publish artifacts
  jobs:
  - job: Publish
    displayName: Publish
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - upload: k8s
      artifact: k8s
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Publish
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: 'App Production AKS'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: KubernetesManifest@0
            displayName: Create imagePullSecret
            inputs:
              action: createSecret
              secretName: $(imagePullSecret)
              kubernetesServiceConnection: 'App Production AKS'
              dockerRegistryEndpoint: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)        
          - task: KubernetesManifest@0
            displayName: Deploy to api Kubernetes cluster
            inputs:
              action: deploy
              kubernetesServiceConnection: 'App Production AKS'
              manifests: |
                $(Pipeline.Workspace)/k8s/aks/api.yaml
              imagePullSecrets: |
                $(imagePullSecret)
              containers: |
                $(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository)-api:$(tag)
```